# Search All only giving last row

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to pull a total of 24 rows from a table in C#, but it is only pulling the last row.

```
static class RoomObjects
{
    public static string buildObjects(int roomid)
    {
        string pList = "";
        MySqlDataReader mysqlRead = DBManager.database.getCommand("SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE `roomid` = " + roomid + "").ExecuteReader();

        while(mysqlRead.Read())
        {
            pList = mysqlRead["id"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["sprite"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["x"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["y"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["z"] + (char)8 + mysqlRead["rotation"] + (char)8;
        }

        DBManager.database.closeClient();

        return pList;
    }
```

I have seen many examples using this technique, have I missed something or do I need to loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time that you assign to `pList`, you override what was previously in it.

If you would like to store your results as string containing each value you would need to append it to the string instead of assigning it. Like this:

```
static class RoomObjects
{
    public static string buildObjects(int roomid)
    {
        string pList = "";
        MySqlDataReader mysqlRead = DBManager.database.getCommand("SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE `roomid` = " + roomid + "").ExecuteReader();

        while(mysqlRead.Read())
        {
            pList += mysqlRead["id"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["sprite"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["x"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["y"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["z"] + (char)8 + mysqlRead["rotation"] + (char)8;

            pList += "," // to separate the values.
        }

        DBManager.database.closeClient();

        return pList;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that!  Nice one, thank you.

Comment: StringBuilder is a better performing choice for more than a couple append calls.

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning your variable every time, instead of appending to it. Try this instead:

```
    var pList = new StringBuilder();
    MySqlDataReader mysqlRead = DBManager.database.getCommand("SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE `roomid` = " + roomid + "").ExecuteReader();

    while(mysqlRead.Read())
    {
        pList.AppendLine(mysqlRead["id"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["sprite"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["x"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["y"].ToString() + (char)8 + mysqlRead["z"] + (char)8 + mysqlRead["rotation"] + (char)8);
    }

    DBManager.database.closeClient();

    return pList.ToString();
```

You can use Append instead of AppendLine if you don't want linebreaks, but I suggest adding something to indicate row separation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your  while loop, you keep replacing `pList`every time the loop runs, maybe try appending or storing those in an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you're setting pList equal to the row, so when you finish, it will only contain the last row you read.

Use pList.Append instead.

(Edit: Oops, read that as a StringBuilder instead of a string.  You could use +=, but a StringBuilder is more efficient.  Then just call the .ToString method to convert it to a string once it's built.)